# An Interesting Model with Unknown Orthogonal Design Matrix

Tags: mixed-model, linear-model, image-processing, manova, signal-processing

Consider a linear mixed model,
$$\mathbf{y}_{ij}=\mathbf{\Gamma}\mathbf{\mu}+\mathbf{z}_i+\mathbf{e}_{ij}, ~~ ~~i=1,\ldots,m,~~j=1,\ldots,n_i,
$$
where $\mathbf{y}_{ij}$ are $k\times 1$ observation vectors,
 $\mathbf{\Gamma}$ is $k\times k$ unknown orthogonal design matrix, $\mathbf{\mu}$ is the unknown $k\times 1$ overall mean, 
the $\mathbf{z}_i$ is the random effect of $ith$ level, and the  $\mathbf{e}_{ij}$ are the errors, and 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{e}_{ij}\mid \mathbf{\Lambda}_0 \overset{iid}{\sim} N_k(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Lambda}_0), ~~ 
\mathbf{z}_i \mid \mathbf{\Lambda}_1 \overset{iid}{\sim}  N_k(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{\Lambda}_1).
\end{equation}
with covariance matrix $\mathbf{\Lambda}_0$ and $\mathbf{\Lambda}_0$.

Has anyone met or handled a similar model? I want to find the application background of this model, for example, signal processing, and image processing. Could you give me some reference or suggestion?